# Migrar jQuery para jQuery2

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho um uma programação na versão do *jquery 1.* * de paginação que está funcionando bem, só que o site está usando *jQuery 2* e como não tenho muito conhecimento desta versão da biblioteca, gostaria de ajuda para fazer funcionar.

este é o **load_mailbox.php**

```
if($_POST['page'])
{
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 15;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;
include"db.php";

$query_pag_data = "SELECT m.id as msgid, m.sender, m.receiver, m.added, m.msg, m.unread, m.poster, m.subject, u.id, u.username, u.class from messages as m LEFT JOIN users as u on m.sender = u.id WHERE m.receiver = 2 LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
$msg = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['subject']);

if ($row['sender'] == 0){

    $row['username'] = "SISTEMA";
}
    $msg .= "<tr>
                 <td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"marcar cinput\" name=\"check\" id=\"check\" value\"".$row['msgid']."\" /></td>
                 <td class=\"mailbox-star\"><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-star-o text-yellow favo\"></i></a></td>                          
                 <td class=\"mailbox-name\"><a href=\"read-mail.html\">".$row['username']." </a></td>
                 <td class=\"mailbox-subject\"><b>".$row['subject']." </b></td>
                 <td class=\"mailbox-date\">".$row['added']."</td>
            </tr>";
}
$msg = "<div class=\"navmp\"><table class=\"table table-hover table-striped\"><tbody>" . $msg . "</tbody></table>"; // Content for Data


/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM messages WHERE receiver = 2";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

/* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
if ($cur_page >= 7) {
    $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
    if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
        $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
    else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
        $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    } else {
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
    }
} else {
    $start_loop = 1;
    if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
        $end_loop = 7;
    else
        $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */



// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg .= "<i p='$pre' class='active'><button class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\"></i></button></i>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg .= "<button class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-left\"></i></button>";
}


// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg .= "<i p='$nex' class='active'><button class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\"></i></button></i>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg .= "<button class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-right\"></i></button>";
}


$msg = $msg . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
echo $msg;
$total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'><b>" . $cur_page . "</b> / <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
echo "<div class=\"pull-right\"><div class=\"btn-group\">" . $total_string . "</div></div>";
}
```

este é a programação em jquery.min que quero fazer funcionar em  jQuery-2.1.3.min.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           function loading_show(){
        $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
    }
    function loading_hide(){
        $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
    } 
        function loadData(page){
           loading_show();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "apps/mailbox/load_mailbox.php",
                data: {page: page},

                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#mp").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    {             
                        loading_hide();
                        $("#mp").html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
        $(document).on('click', '.navmp i.active', function(){
            var page = $(this).attr('p');
            loadData(page);

        });
```

uso o bootstrap, mais não quero usar o datatables por questão de customização.

desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Eu tbm achei que sim, mais ele não funciona no  jQuery-2.1.3.min.js e se eu por exemplo chamar o jquery.min assim:  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> ele funciona perfeito mais a página que chamo não funciona menu nem nada.

Comment: não pq se eu tirar ele para de funcionar e todo resto volta, o erro que vi no fire bug foi "TypeError: $(...).live is not a function" entaum troquei para $(document).on('click', '.navmp i.active', function(){ o erro para mais nada é exibido na página.

Comment: Entendi, vou remover meus comentários para não "*sujar*" a pergunta. Alguma [dessas soluções](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14354040/4056678) resolvem?

Comment: eu já tinha visto isto não resolvveu mais olhei na resposta do jquery no firebug e ele está trazendo só não exibe :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde o jQuery1.8 o metodo `.ajaxComplete()` só pode ser usado com `document`

Realmente não entendi o por que foi usado `.ajaxComplete` dentro de um callback, acredito que ele não seja necessário neste ponto e que talvez você deva remove-lo ou apenas ajustar ao elemento anexado necessário (uma vez apenas, há um exemplo mais abaixo para isto).

Eu recomendo usar o `Promise` no `.ajax` também, o código deve ficar algo como:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "apps/mailbox/load_mailbox.php",
    data: {page: page}
}).done(function(msg) {            
    loading_hide();
    $("#mp").html(msg);//Exibe o HTML
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert([jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown]);//Se necessitar tratar os erros
});
```

A função `.ajaxComplete` é um evento que monitora as requisições ajax, eu acredito que no seu código ele não seja necessário, mas se for, então adicione ele desta maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {             
        console.log(event, request, settings); //Exemplo de monitoramento
    });

    function loading_show() {
        $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
    }
```

Comment: simplesmente perfeito obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: @opeta Por nada, mais uma vez seja bem vindo, queria lhe convidar a participar da eleição para moderador, é a primeira eleição do StackOverflow Portugues ~> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1 Pode votar em 3 usuários (por enquanto estamos em fase de indicações para conhecer os candidatos). Um abraço e sucesso com seu projeto.

Comment: você está participando? tem alguém que quer que indique? sei como é difícil achar bons moderadores, e por isso é importante conhecer o trabalho da pessoa indicada. Amanhã vou ler a página da eleição.

Comment: Não estou não, pode escolher o candidato que mais lhe agradar, tem 2 dias antes de começar as primarias :) Eu acho que é um processo interessante para o SOpt e você parece ser participativo, gostaria que participa-se da primeira eleição e convida-se quem você conhecer que participa do SOpt a participar também. Você pode escolher três moderadores, ok até amanhã @opeta vou descansar tambem